# Does lost mode post more frequent updates?

Tags: find-my, airtag

When trying to follow an AirTag attached to a dog’s collar, it’s very hard to locate them if they’re on the run, since location updates might only happen every 3-5 minutes, even with a full battery.

Is there a way to get more frequent updates on an AirTag? E.g. by enabling Lost Mode or a similar feature?

Comment: Is the dog always in range of an iPhone or similar?

Comment: @nohillside: Yeah. For example, I would notice the same problem if a dog walker with an iPhone was walking the dog.

Comment: Then wouldn't this be a simple empirical test?